# Comunicação de um cliente Android com servidor Python

Tags: android, python

Tenho um servidor extremamente básico em Python e um cliente Android, mas eu não consigo estabelecer a conexão. Eu tenho um cliente feito também em Python e outro em Java, e ambos conectam perfeitamente ao servidor.

Já tentei diferentes versões do Android, já desabilitei antivírus e firewall do windows mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Seguem os códigos:

Código Python

```
#Programa Servidor
import socket

host = "" #IP do servidor
port = 5000 #Porta disponível do servidor

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #Cria um novo socket
s.bind((host, port)) #Vincula o socket ao IP e Porta correspondente
s.listen(5) #Define o limite de conexões

print("Aguardando conexao...")

conn, addr = s.accept() #Aceita a conexão

print("Connected by", addr)

data = conn.recv(1024)

#print(data.decode())

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024) #Aguarda uma determinada informação enviada de um remoto

    print(repr(data)) #Converte a informação para string

    if(repr(data)=="b'sair'"):
        estado = 1

conn.close()
```

Código do Android Studio

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.usuario.testesocket.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Conecta"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Classe principal

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button conectar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        if (conectar != null) {
            conectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    new Thread(new ClienteThread()).start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Classe da Thread

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by Jefferson on 27/05/2016.
 */
public class ClienteThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A aplicação é bem simples, apenas gostaria de visualizar que o servidor recebeu a conexão do cliente android.

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Pode postar o erro? Ou até mesmo o trace da execução já que vc tem alguns debugs pelo caminho ali.

Comment: O erro era que estava faltando permissão de uso da rede no AndroidManifest.xml